# A very curious rational fraction that converges. What is the value?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, trigonometry

Is there any closed form for the following limit?

> Define the sequence
>   $$ \begin{cases} 
>   a_{n+1} = b_n+2a_n + 14\\
>   b_{n+1} = 9b_n+ 2a_n+70
> \end{cases}$$
>   with initial values $a_0 = b_0 = 1$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = ? $

The limit is approximately $0.1376$. My math teacher [Carlos Ivorra](https://www.uv.es/ivorra) says that this limit have a closed form involving the sine of an angle. What is the closed form for is limit?

NOTE: I have found this (and another series of converging sequences) by the use of an ancient method for calculating sines recently rediscovered. I'll give the details soon as a more general question.

Comment: This becomes sensible in the context of linear algebra: the triple $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1},1)$ is expressed by a matrix multiplication applied to  $(a_n,b_n,1)$. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors determine the asymptotic behavior, in the sense that the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue will dominate, in general. Is this familiar-sounding stuff?

Comment: Everybody has avoided the question of the closed form involving a sinus.!!!

Comment: @Piquito there is no reasonable way to involve trigonometry here.

Comment: Without the perturbation, this would have been effectively the power method for finding an eigenvector.

Comment: @WillJagy I mildly disagree. paulgarret points out the system can be seen as a perspective problem, involving 2D-homogeneous vectors $v=(a_n,b_n,1)$ and a $3 \times 3$ homography matrix $H$. As $v$ is left-multiplied by $H$ repeatedly, it aligns with the eigenvector of greatest eigenvalue, which points at a particular angle in 2D-space (after perspective division using the eigenvector's third component). Viewed that way, I'm sure dividing the first component of this vector by the second involves a $\sin()$ somewhere, and this ratio is also independent of the perspective division step.

Comment: @paulgarrett You got me interested. The eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue will dominate iff starting point $(1,1,1)$ has non-zero component associated with it in the basis of eigenvectors. It is so in this particular case, but in general we should check that. Otherwise we should consider the eigenvector with next largest eigenvalue and so on. And "largest" meaning "with largest modulus". Am I right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, indeed, you're correct. Of course, the odds are good that a fairly random vector _does_ contain a non-zero component for the largest (in modulus, yes) eigenvector, but in either aritificially posed situations, and/or some significant natural situations, it might be a delicate issue whether the largest occurs or not. Observational error and such? Potential instability.

Comment: @WillJagy You can easily get a trig equation for the limit, but it doesn't seem very useful. From the answers we know $2\mu^2 + 7\mu - 1 = 0$. Let $\mu = \sin\theta$, and we get $\cos 2\theta = 7 \sin \theta$. But so what?

Comment: @WillJagy: the sinus is mentioned by the OP in the post.

Comment: @Piquito right. I understood that you found it there. Actually, about seven hours ago the OP added this: "NOTE: I have found this (and another series of converging sequences) by the use of an ancient method for calculating sines recently rediscovered. I'll give the details soon as a more general question."  I guess we will find out the meaning of this within a few days.

Comment: @WillJagy This is the trigonometric expression I am refering to:  $ -\sin\left (  \frac{\pi}{4}\right )\tan\left (\frac{1}{2} \cot^{-1}\frac{-7}{2\sqrt{2}} \right ) $ (I'm the OP.)

Comment: @FractionalInquirer You should try to [merge your accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @FractionalInquirer: In general, $\tan( \frac12 \cot^{-1}(x) ) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-x$ for any $x > 0$, so it's not very meaningful to use such a trigonometric expression unless it is related in some elegant way to the original question. ($\sin(\frac{π}{4})$ is a red-herring.)

Answer (score 31):

If $\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n} }{b_{n} } $exists then 
$$
\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1} }{b_{n+1} } =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n+2a_n + 14}{9b_n+ 2a_n+70 }\\=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{b_{n} }{b_{n} }+2\frac{a_{n} }{b_{n} } + \frac{14 }{b_{n} }}{9\frac{b_{n} }{b_{n} }+ 2\frac{a_{n} }{b_{n} }+\frac{70 }{b_{n} } }\\
=\frac{1+2\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{a_{n} }{b_{n} }) + \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{14 }{b_{n} })}{9+ 2\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{a_{n} }{b_{n} })+\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{70 }{b_{n} }) }\\
=\frac{1+2\mu+ 0}{9+ 2\mu+0}
$$
Here we used the fact that ${b}_{{n}}>{n}$ and therefore $$0\leq~\lim_{{n}\to\infty}~{\frac{1}{{b}_{{n}}}}<\lim_{{n}\to\infty}~{\frac{1}{{n}}}\leq0$$

So 
$$2\mu^2+7\mu-1=0$$.
But $\mu \gt 0$, so
$$\mu={{\sqrt{57}-7}\over{4}}
  $$

Comment: See my answer for proof that the limit exists, as well as some details of the convergence behaviour.

Comment: For completeness, you may want to give a reason for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$ being $0$.

Comment: From my calculator: 0.13745860881768742430917120173653, so the original statement is incorrect, the limit is closer to **0.1375**, not 0.1376.

Comment: @KlausDraeger I hope the sentence I added makes  this clear.

Comment: @MarkLakata You are right. Maybe the OP wanted to write 0.13746 and lost a digit,

Answer (score 26):

One idea to get the limit in closed form :

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
2 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$, $X_n = \begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix}$, and $b=\begin{pmatrix} 14 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}$.

You can write $X_{n+1} = AX_n + b$. The idea is to solve the equation $X=AX+b$ ($X$ being a two-dimensional vector) - this equation has a unique solution as $(A-I)$ is non-singular. Let's call $X$ this solution; you can write $(X_{n+1}-X)=A(X_n - X)$ then, for all $n$, you have :

\begin{equation}
(X_{n} - X ) =A^n (X_{0} - X)
\end{equation}

$A^n$ can be evaluated by diagonalizing $A$. This will give you $X_n$ (and then $a_n$ and $b_n$ in closed form).

Answer (score 8):

The requested limit is:
$$ \frac{4 \sqrt{57} - 20}{4 \sqrt{57} + 44} \approx 0.1374586  $$
This is
$$ \frac{ \sqrt{57} - 5}{ \sqrt{57} + 11}   $$
and rationalizing the denominator gives
$$ \frac{ \sqrt{57} - 7}{ 4}   $$

$$ a_{n+2} = 11 a_{n+1} - 16 a_n - 42  $$

$$ b_{n+2} = 11 b_{n+1} - 16 b_n - 42  $$

The separate linear recurrences are the result of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem applied to the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
2 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$
although I wrote everything out in detail because I was not sure what the constant terms $14,70$ would do.

Hmmm. Good thing I was careful, it was not necessary that the 42's come out the same. Given the matrix system $X_{n+1} = A X_n + B,$ where $\tau = \operatorname{trace} A$ and $\delta = \det A,$ we get
$$ X_{n+2} = \tau X_{n+1} - \delta X_n + (A - (\tau - 1)I) B. $$
There is no reason to expect the two components of $(A - (\tau - 1)I) B$ to come out the same, it was arranged for this particular problem. Indeed, here
$$
(A - (\tau - 1)I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{6}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so to get the two constants the same it was required to take the constant vector $B$ as a scalar multiple of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
1  \\
1 
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
2  \\
10 
\end{array}
\right),
$$
and they multiplied this by $7.$

$$ a_n = \left( 4 - \frac{20}{\sqrt{57}} \right) \left( \frac{11 + \sqrt {57}}{2} \right)^n + \left( 4 + \frac{20}{\sqrt{57}} \right) \left( \frac{11 - \sqrt {57}}{2} \right)^n - 7   $$
$$ b_n = \left( 4 + \frac{44}{\sqrt{57}} \right) \left( \frac{11 + \sqrt {57}}{2} \right)^n + \left( 4 - \frac{44}{\sqrt{57}} \right) \left( \frac{11 - \sqrt {57}}{2} \right)^n - 7   $$

Answer (score 6):

Here is a rigorous and systematic way to analyze the existence and value of the limit. (*miracle173*'s answer didn't prove existence but uses essentially the same method for finding the value if it exists.)

Let $c_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ (for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Then $b_{n+1} c_{n+1} = b_n + 2 b_n c_n + 14$.

And $b_{n+1} = 9 b_n + 2 b_n c_n + 70$.

Thus $c_{n+1} = \dfrac{ b_n + 2 b_n c_n + 14 }{ 9 b_n + 2 b_n c_n + 70 } = \dfrac{ 1 + 2 c_n + \frac{14}{b_n} }{ 9 + 2 c_n + \frac{70}{b_n} }$.

Let $r = \dfrac{\sqrt{57}-7}{4}$ so that $r = \dfrac{1+2r}{9+2r}$, and let $d_n = c_n - r$.

Take any $ε > 0$, and let "$[x]$" denote "$\{ t : t \in \mathbb{R} \land |t| \le x \}$".

Then $c_{n+1} \in \dfrac{ 1 + 2 c_n }{ 9 + 2 c_n } + [ε]$ as $n \to \infty$, since $b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Then $d_{n+1} \in \dfrac{ 1 + 2 (r+d_n) }{ 9 + 2 (r+d_n) } + [ε] - r = \dfrac{ 2 - 2 r }{ 9 + 2 (r+d_n) } d_n + [ε] \subseteq [\frac29 d_n] + [ε]$.

Thus $d_n \in [2ε]$ eventually as $n \to \infty$, since $\frac29 x + 1 < x - \frac12$ for any $x > 2$.

Therefore since $ε$ was arbitrary, $d_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Note that this technique applies to many such iterative processes, where we attempt to isolate the significant terms and analyze the remainder. Also, one can usually easily recover hard bounds on the convergence behaviour. In this case, one only needs to know how large $n$ must be for the $[ε]$ error bound to hold, and we could if desired compute an upper bound on $d_n$ after that point by solving $d_{n+1} = \frac29 d_n + ε$. I didn't do that here because we didn't need it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Define

$$ L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} $$
$$ r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_n} $$
$$ s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} $$

then it's not hard to see that $L = r/s$. Also, by substituting in the recursion, since we have $b_n \to \infty$ we can compute

$$ r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + 2 \frac{a_n}{b_n} + \frac{14}{b_n}\right) = 1 + 2L $$
$$ s = \ldots = 9 + 2L $$

(the reason to define $r$ and $s$ is precisely because I wanted to simplify the recursions in this fashion)

Solving the system of equations, along with $L>0$,  gives

$$ L = \frac{-7 + \sqrt{57}}{4} $$